# R Shiny SlickR Change Background Color

Tags: r, shiny

I've got an R Shiny dashboard, and adding the package [slickR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/slickR/vignettes/shiny.html), which works.  However, i'm struggling to set the whitespace on side of each image to my desired color.  Suggestions?  I've even tried CSS and that doesn't seem to take.

```
          fluidRow(
            tags$div(
              slickROutput("slickr"),
              #style='background-color:red;' # didnt' work, got overwritten by slickR
            ) #close tags
          ) #close fluidRow
```

```
  output$slickr <- renderSlickR({
    imgs <- list.files("images/", pattern=".jpg", full.names = TRUE)
    slickR(obj = imgs ,slideId = 'ex1',height = 450, width='100%') 
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate `.css` file and add the custom styling there to prevent it getting overwritten in the style attribute.

**ui.R**

```r
fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "slickr.css")
  ),
  ...,
  fluidRow(
    column(12, slickROutput("slickr"))
  )
)
```

**www/slickr.css**

```
#slickr {
  background-color: red;
}
```

There is more information about CSS here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html